# Display preview of camera using external camera

Tags: android, camera

I want to display preview of camera using external camera. Can we use `surfaceView` for this or not? Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: can u explain more in detail ..

Comment: i am not getting your Question.

Comment: Yes Hasmukh ,Actually i have to display preview of camera for inbuilt camera we use serfaceView but i have to use external camera so i'm displaying preview using canvas .But I want to know that can we use srfaceView for display preview of external camera .If this is possible then how,By using this code will be very efficient and less also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
......
SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = preview.getHolder();
camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); 
......
```

Comment: Thanks appserv but Tell me in detail ,Actually i'm not getting.